# Help Contacting Patent Owner

Tags: ownership

In reference to the patent: [CA2356488A1](https://www.google.com/patents/CA2356488A1)

How would I get in contact with Mr. Douglas?  I might be interested in buying this patent from him. Any help is greatly appreciated.